# MongoDB persisting order of nested documents in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm very confused about this topic. Initially I planned my DB without any "sorting" fields and would just push values in array in the order that I wanted. Everything worked fine until one day one of my collections array got randomly shuffled.

Google gives me a lot of controversial information on whether MongoDB persists order in arrays or not.

To make it even more confusing `$push` has `$sort` modifier. I don't understand why would it be there unless arrays are actually stay persistent (but my practice tells me they are not!). Why would anyone want to push values in an array in certain order when it can be shuffled at any random time?

Also what's the best way to keep the order in DB? I ended up adding `order` field. But the problem is that my documents have a lot of nested (and sub nested) docs that need to be presented in a certain order. As I know, the only way to order items in nested array is to use aggregation: `unwind` -> `sort` -> `group`. But that looks like a lot of steps if I have quite a bit of fields that I need to sort. Perhaps would be better way to sort it after querying the document?

Answer (score 3):

Alright, after a lot of googling and chatting with MongoDB Atlas support, I can confirm that arrays in MongoDB DO persist their order. Most likely we had a bug on application layer that messed up with arrays.